# Is CLion doesn't support .lib file(generated by visual studio)

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, lib

I am new to clion and cmake. I just created a simple static library project in vc 2017 and i copied the .lib file to lib folder inside the clion project (also copied the .h file in vc to include dir inside the clion project)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(ex_lib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(PROJECT_LINK_LIBS created_lib.lib)

link_directories(lib)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(ex_lib main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ex_lib ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS})
```

but it gives me an following error

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ex_lib.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable ex_lib.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcreated_lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\ex_lib.dir\build.make:85: recipe for target 'ex_lib.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ex_lib.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:83: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ex_lib.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'ex_lib' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [ex_lib.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ex_lib.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ex_lib.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [ex_lib] Error 2
```

May be i have done something wrong with cmake. or vc makes lib file using vc++ that doesn't supported in clion.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think you can link a library built with MSC in a MinGW build. I think you should configure CLion to use MSC instead of MinGW or rebuild the lib using MinGW

Comment: how to use MinGW compiler in vc 2017

Comment: mingw uses .a library files, not .lib from VS. Use VS or make CLion use VS compielrs.

Comment: Its working. Thanks . I changed to vs compiler.